# Pandas read_fwf ignores columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .asc file where each line has 655 entries and looks somewhat like the following (note the leading whitespace)

```
 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ... -999 -999
```

When I read the file using pandas read_fwf

```
data = pd.read_fwf('Users/.../file.asc', index_col=False, sep=' ', skiprows=6, header=None, na_values=[-999])
```

the first three columns are thrown into the 0 column such that I obtain the output

```
                   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   ...   641  \
0  -999 -999 -999 -999  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
```

It seems like the function interprets my first 4 columns as an index. `index_col=False` didn't help fixing the problem. Also, I tried to let pandas create an index column but couldn't find this feature.

Looking forward to your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** using `colspecs` parameter when calling `read_fwf()`

```
In [83]: df = pd.read_fwf(fn, skiprows=6, header=None, na_values=[-999],
   ....:                  colspecs=[(5,6)] * 654)


In [84]: df.head()
Out[84]:
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   ...   644  645  646  647  648  649  650  651  652  653
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[5 rows x 654 columns]
```

**UPDATE:**

use `read_csv()` instead of `read_fwf()` and it'll work:

```
In [61]: fn = r'D:\download\BRD_8110_YY_GIS.asc'

In [62]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, skiprows=6, header=None, na_values=[-999], delim_whitespace=True)

In [63]: df.head()
Out[63]:
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   ...   644  645  646  647  648  649  650  651  652  653
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[5 rows x 654 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sep='\s+'`as keyword argument as stated in the current documentation for [pandas - read_fwf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) to accept 1 or more white space characters as spearators for fields. I would be reluctant in supplying `'\s*'` as this means 0 or more which might get you into trouble ;-)

Comment: don't you want to change `'\s+\'` to `'\s+'` ? ;)

Comment: Yes, good catch @MaxU. Editing in text areas is not my best skill. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however that did not do the trick. Actually, that did not do anything at all to the result. Maybe I should add to this discussion that every line in the raw data has a leading whitespace, maybe that is important (I just edited my initial post). Do you have any other guess?

Comment: I also tested delim_whitespace=True as suggested by @MaxU but that did not work either. I also set up a new .asc file with only one row where I deleted the leading whitespace - this however does not seem to cause the problem as the problem remains the same. I got the same result when I deleted the first 4 entries.

Comment: @Justus, could you upload somewhere your file or part of it and post here a link to it, so we could reproduce your problem?

Comment: @MaxU Sure, have a look here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gpj8a7tixdi2r7i/AABQ8kADmbpWBjGv65Jw1nMOa?dl=0 I stripped down the python code to the few relevant lines. A note to keep me out of trouble: I obtained the dataset from the German Weather Service DWD.